# UtteranceProgressListener is not getting called in api level above 21

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I want to know why my UtteranceProgressListener is not getting called.
Here is how i am trying to do this

```
 private UtteranceProgressListener progressListener=new UtteranceProgressListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
        Log.d("modroid", "speech started");

    }

    @Override
    public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
        Log.d("modroid", "done");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(String utteranceId) {
        Log.d("modroid", "error");

    }
};

  private void prepareTxtToSpeech() {
    textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(context, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                if (textToSpeech.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.US) == TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE) {
                    textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                    textToSpeech.setSpeechRate(0.8f);
                    textToSpeech.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(progressListener);
                }
            } else if (status == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.txttospeech_error), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

here is how i am calling speaking method

```
   public void speak(String text) {
    if (textToSpeech != null) {

        Log.d("modroid", "speaking: ");
        textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "some id");
    }
}
```

I know this type of questions has been asked before but nothing helped me. Please let me know where i am doing mistake.

Comment: Put some logging inside and outside of `textToSpeech.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.US) == TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE` does it return true or false?

Comment: yes it is returning false. What should i do then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be careful how you 'validate' if a language is available and also if it sets correctly:

```
    switch (textToSpeech.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.US)){

        case TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE:
            break;
        case TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE:
            break;
        case TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_VAR_AVAILABLE:
            break;
        case TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA:
            break;
        case TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED:
            break;
    }
```

You should also check the response of `textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH)` in the same way.

One of the top three would probably be acceptable to you. Otherwise, you would need to handle the problem.

[setLanguage()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setLanguage(java.util.Locale))

[isLanguageAvailable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#isLanguageAvailable(java.util.Locale))